# Monitoring motherboard voltages

Tags: motherboard, power-supply, power

I have been testing different hardware monitoring software, both Linux and Windows, and noticed there is typically only CPU and RAM voltages offered if any at all. Id like to find tools that will give me the voltage readings from the PSU (without using the BIOS) and some readings on other parts of the system like the expansion slots and USB ports. The closest I got was using lm-sensors to get what appears to be the expansion slots:

[image]

I started trying to determine what sensors a motherboard even has but i haven't been able to come up with anything. I tried looking into specific areas of the mobo such as the PCH thinking maybe like the CPU and RAM notable components might contain sensors, No luck there either.

I tried my mobo manual but it only list it's monitoring capabilities, it says nothing about individual sensors or what can be done with them:

[image]

I've been at it all day and gotten absolutely nowhere, any info on what sensors a typical motherboard contains or tools that can do what im looking for would be appreciated.

My motherboard is a Gigabyte ga-z77x-ud3h rev. 1.0, more concerned with the issue in general than my specific setup though.

Comment: Might want to look at `lmsensors` on *nix systems, and `gkrellm` on Linux.  Not sure where it reads data from.

Answer (score 1):

You can access these (voltage) values with a protocol named [System Management Bus](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/System_Management_Bus). For Windows, there is [SMBus.org](http://smbus.org/drivers/).

You can get the SMBus access via [ACPI](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Advanced_Configuration_and_Power_Interface), but you need a kernel driver for this.
Lots of coding to do, but it's possible.
Fortunately, the protocol is generic - so it's the same for every (recent) 
motherboard.

> any info on what sensors a typical motherboard contains or tools that can do what im looking for would be appreciated.

AFAIK this information is disclosed by the respective ACPI tables. So read the tables and display their data.